# Enabling a Textbox and making it editable

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, dojo

I have a textbox field displayed in my jsp file which looks always disabled and uneditable. I would like to have it enabled and editable on one condition.

So when the above condition is satisfied, I will save the page which save this field in DB. I would just like to have the text box enabled and the field editable. My code is as follows,

```
    <li class="Textbox"><input type="text"
                                            dojoType="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" name="field name"
                                                id="EDIT21" style="width: 45px;" size="4" maxlength="3"
                                            value="${value of an expression}"
                                            onchange="Config1.updateStatus();" required="true"
                                            constraints="{min:1,max:999}" 
                                            rangeMessage="<spring:message code='validation.' arguments='1,999' />" />
                                    </li>
```

Comment: "which looks always disabled and uneditable" <- *is* it disabled/uneditable or does it just *look* disabled/uneditable?

Comment: It is disabled/uneditable. Because on one condition the value is displayed as a label . But on another condition as above, the value is displayed in the text box which is uneditable.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in that code that would cause the textbox to behave like that.  It sounds like you've either got some javascript disabling the textbox, or some CSS that makes it appear as though it's disabled even though it's not.  If it's Javascript, look for a line that sets the disabled property, such as

```
document.getElementById('EDIT21').disabled = true;
```

or

```
document.getElementbyId('EDIT21').contentEditable = false;
```

Comment: Also check that your javascript function Config1.updateStatus isn't returning false.